# Kernel and Range of a Linear transformation Inclusions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

For a linear algebra problem, I want to proof three things. The first one is that, for a linear transformation $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $Im(f^2) \subset Im(f)$. The second one is that, for that same linear transformation $f$, $Ker(f) \subset Ker(f^2)$. The last one is a bit more tricky: $Ker(f) = Ker(f^2) \iff \mathbb{R}^n = Im(f) \oplus Ker(f)$, for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

For the first one, I am stuck. I think it might go like this: let $v\in Im(f^2)$, then we define $w = f(v)$ and therefore $f(f(v)) = f(w)$, thus $v \in Im(f)$. I don't know if it is correct or eve "legal". Besides, if it is, I don't see WHY this should be true.

For the second one, here is what I did: let $v \in Ker(f)$, then $f(v) = 0$ and hence $f(f(v)) = f(0) = 0$, since $f$ is linear. Therefore $v \in Ker(f^2)$. Again, I think this is correct but I don't see WHY it should be like that.

For the third one I have no clue. Can somebody explain all of this? Why and how to prove it? And by why I mean some intuition, I think I lack that.

Comment: What is meant by $f^2$? The composition $f\circ f$ is not well-defined because you'd need $n=m$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edited it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good. Just need to write in a proper way.
**Hints**

- Let $u\in Im(f)$, then $f(w)=u$ for some $w\in \Bbb{R}^n$.if $v\in Im(f^2)$, then $v=f^2(w)$ for some $w \in \Bbb{R}^n$, $v=f(f(w))$, $v=f(u)$, thus $v\in Im(f)$. Thus $Im(f^2)\subseteq Im(f)$.
  Similarly, $Ker(f)\subseteq Ker(f^2)$.

Your second proof is absolutely correct.

- If $x\in Ker (f)$, then $f(x)=0\Rightarrow f(f(x))=f(0)=0$. Therefore, $x\in Ker(f^2).$ Thus $Ker(f)\subseteq Ker(f^2)$

Go through this **proposition"**, You can prove the third.

- Proposition: Let $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n$ satisfy $fof=f$. Show that $\Bbb{R}^n= Ker(f)\oplus Im(f)$.

Write $v\in\Bbb{R}^n$, as $v=fv+(v-fv)$ and $f(v)\in Im(f)$, $v-f(v)\in Ker(f)$.
Now proceed...

**Note** Here, $f^2=fof$.